# WinRT - Roaming App Settings - Are they persisted across versions?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I was reading the MSDN article about "Accessing App Data with WinRT":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx

In the section **Roaming App Data** it says:

> If the app data on a device is updated to a new version because the
>   user installed a newer version of the app, its app data is copied to
>   the cloud. The system does not update app data to other devices on
>   which the user has the app installed until the app is updated on those
>   devices as well.

It also says that the **Roaming App Data** is deleted if the app is not used for 30 days.

I think that "Roaming App Data" refers to `ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder`.

I don't understand if the same thing applies to **Roaming Settings** (`ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values`). Are they also not shared across versions? Are they also deleted after not using app for 30 days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RoamingSettings` use the same engine as the roaming application folder. So, the same restrictions apply. Data may be expired after 30 days if not accessed.

I'd suggest you consider the roaming settings as a convenience, and if the 30 days will be an issue, keep important settings locally and consider the roaming as a convenient way to synchronize settings when the application is used more frequently. You could also potentially use something like OneDrive to store settings if needed.

There are group policy settings that can disable roaming and OneDrive though.

Comment: Thanks. In that case I will probably end up adding\setting data to both LocalSettings and RoamingSettings. When reading\getting data, I will check both LocalSettings and RoamingSettings, if one of them is missing the data I will update it as well.